# Parsing CSV with custom separator column isn't mapping appropriately to POJO

Tags: java, csv, spring-boot

While parsing CSV with with a custom column separator ';' and using :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;
```

I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Author] from String value ('Email;FirstName;LastName'); no single-String constructor/factory method
```

here is my parsing code:

```
public static <T> List<T> loadObjectList(Class<T> type, String fileName) {
     CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema();
     bootstrapSchema.withColumnSeparator(';').withoutQuoteChar();
     CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
     File file = new File(fileName);
     MappingIterator<T> readValues = 
         mapper.reader(type)
            .with(bootstrapSchema)
            .readValues(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "ISO-8859-1"));
     return readValues.readAll();
}
```

and here is my model i want to map to CSV to:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "Email", "FirstName", "LastName" })
public class Author {

    String Email;
    String FirstName;
    String LastName;

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public Author(String email, String firstName, String lastName) {
        Email = email;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to def constructor with single `String` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case,
the solution to your problem is this: Pay attention to the exception message.

Here is the exception message that you included:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Author] from String value ('Email;FirstName;LastName'); no single-String constructor/factory method

Here is a 3 step solution to your question:

Step 1: Notice this in the exception message: **no single-String constructor/factory method**

Step 2: Take a look at the `Author` class that you included.
Notice that it does not include either a constructor or a factory method that accepts
exactly one String as a parameter.

Step 3: Add a constructor to the `Author` class that accepts a single String as the parameter.

Here is some code (this is not the final code, you will need to add error handling):

```
public Author(final String line)
{
  final String[] lineContentArray = line.split(";");

  // Note: consider using the standard java field naming convention.
  email = line[0];
  firstName = line[1];
  lastName = line[2];
}
```

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Instead of addressing the problem, it reimplements CSV parsing (poorly, it doesn't deal with separators in values, quoting and a variety of other CSV aspects that Jackson is designed to deal with). The answer by @Bor Laze is the correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema();
bootstrapSchema.withColumnSeparator(';').withoutQuoteChar();
```

I'm not sure in this part - it's not a builder pattern.

Try

```
CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().bootstrapSchema.withColumnSeparator(';').withoutQuoteChar();
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer indeed allows solving the OP issue according to the suggestion on the exception message.
However, the whole point in using `CSVMapper` is about not writing code for the split around separator and assignment to fields. That is what the lib is supposed to do.

As I encountered same issue, I digged up a bit and found the following. It is all about using `typedSchemaFor` where `type` is the target class.
Indeed bit disturbing to have to pas the `type` as to both mapper and schema.

```
ObjectReader objectReader() {
  CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
  CsvSchema schema = schema(mapper);
  return mapper.readerFor(type).with(schema);
}
    
CsvSchema schema(CsvMapper mapper) {
  return mapper.typedSchemaFor(type)
    .withColumnSeparator(';')
    .withoutHeader()
    .withoutQuoteChar();
}
```